# Отправка больших файлов по протоколу UDP

Tags: c++, qt, сеть, udp

Я пытаюсь отправить большой файл через протокол *UDP*. Но дело в том, что через *UDP* нельзя отправить файлы более 8k байт.

Как мне разбить свой файл, который засунут в `QByteArray` на более мелкие файлы и отправить несколькими датаграмами на сервер?

Код клиента:

```
void client::sendDatagrams(){
    QByteArray data;
    QFile* file = new QFile("test");
    file->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString hash_summ = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(data,QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());
    qDebug() << "Hash: " << hash_summ;
    data = file->readAll();
    qDebug() << "File size: " << data.size();
    qDebug() <<"Text: " <<data;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
        Client_Socket->writeDatagram(data , QHostAddress::LocalHost,1234);
    }
}
```

Comment: В [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qudpsocket.html) не нашёл упоминания об ограничении размера отправляемых датаграмм. Поправьте, если что-то не знаю.

Comment: UDP использовать принципально? Вообще под эту задачу больше подходит TCP.

Comment: @aleks.andr , да, есть [такое](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#writeDatagram).

Comment: @ alexis031182 Позвольте, здесь написано: `Sending datagrams larger than 512 bytes is in general disadvised, as even if they are sent successfully, they are likely to be fragmented by the IP layer before arriving at their final destination.` Т.е. отправка датаграмм большего размера прямо не запрещается, лишь предупреждается о том, что они будут фрагментированы.

Comment: @aleks.andr , Вы проигнорировали абзац, расположенный выше процитированного Вами текста по предоставленной мною ссылке.

Comment: @aleks.andr , пожалуйста, не ставьте символ пробела между знаком `@` и ником, иначе адресат не получит уведомления о сообщении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, что подойдёт такое решение:

```
void client::sendDatagrams() {
    QFile file("test.dat");
    if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
        // Размер прочитанных из файла данных
        // и текущее смещение от начала файла.
        qint64 raw_size = 0, raw_offset = 0;

        // Константный размер датаграммы.
        const qint64 datagram_size = 512;

        // Буфер для временного хранения данных.
        char raw_data[datagram_size];

        // Файл читаем последовательно и ровно столько байт за итерацию,
        // сколько может быть размещено в буфере.
        while((raw_size = file.readData(raw_data, datagram_size)) > 0) {
            // Метод fromRawData() не производит копирование данных.
            QByteArray data
                = QByteArray::fromRawData(raw_data, raw_size);

            // Вычисление хэш-суммы.
            QByteArray hash
                = QCryptographicHash::hash(data
                    , QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex();

            // Итоговая датаграмма.
            QByteArray datagram;

            // Заполнять её лучше через QDataStream,
            // поскольку на приёмной стороне будет проще
            // произвести обратные действия,
            // чтобы восстановить исходные данные.

            // Смещение (raw_offset) сохраняем для того,
            // чтобы на приёмной стороне иметь возможность
            // воспроизвести порядок следования датаграмм,
            // т.к. при использовании UDP, последние могут
            // приходить без соблюдения очерёдности.

            QDataStream stream(&datagram, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
            stream << raw_offset;
            stream << hash;
            stream << data;

            Client_Socket->writeDatagram(datagram
                , QHostAddress::LocalHost, 1234);

            // Обновление смещения.
            raw_offset += raw_size;
        }
    }
}
```

**Добавлено**

Реализация приёмника может отличаться от кода в листинге, приведённом ниже, в зависимости от конкретной задачи. Но, предположим, требуется просто сохранить полученное содержимое файла.

Разумеется, что прежде чем мы сможем записать данные в файл, его необходимо подготовить. Для этого от отправляющей стороны перед пересылкой содержимого файла должен быть получен его размер. В исходнике выше этот подготовительный момент не рассматривается, т.к. его реализация фактически ничем не отличается от передачи содержимого файла, да и зависит от предпочтений автора кода.

Предположим, что мы уже получили размер отправляемого приёмнику файла, либо он известен нам заранее. Тогда создаём чистый файл и изменяем его размер аккурат требуемому:

```
// Файл будет заполнен нулями.
QFile file("test-out.dat");
file.resize(file_size);
```

Далее можно принимать содержимое:

```
void receiver::readPendingDatagrams() {
    while(socket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());

        socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());

        // При считывании данных из потока важно соблюдать
        // их очерёдность и тип.

        // Можно не опасаться того, что hash и data
        // имеют одинаковый тип, т.к. QDataStream
        // корректно обработает данную ситуацию.

        QDataStream stream(datagram);

        qint64 offset = 0;
        stream >> offset;

        QByteArray hash;
        stream >> hash;

        QByteArray data;
        stream >> data;

        // Проверяем хэш-сумму.
        if(QCryptographicHash::hash(data
            , QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex() != hash) {

            // В случае несовпадения реагируем,
            // исходя из требований задачи.
            continue;
        }

        // Сохраняем данные, учитывая смещение.
        if(file.open(QFile::WriteOnly)) {
            QDataStream stream(&file, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
            if(stream.skipRawData(offset) == offset) {
                stream << data;
            }

            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Добавлено**

Если нет уверенности, что управляющая датаграмма, содержащая размер файла, дойдёт в целости и сохранности, то, как вариант, эти данные можно отправить по TCP/IP. Получится механизм, схожий в чём-то с торрентами.

Comment: Тут еще интересно, как файл собрать на приемнике. Может добавите в ответ?

Comment: Наверное в самом конце надо послать еще одну datagram (все, конец данных). Или предусмотреть такой признак в формате всех datagram.. А как иначе приемник узнает, что прочел уже весь файл?

Comment: @user3195373 , добавил.

Comment: @avp , можно различно, но я бы просто отправил первым пакетом размер данных. Код будет аналогичен отправке содержимого данных. Ну или чтобы не заморачиваться, действительно, можно просто в каждой датаграмме слать размер всего файла.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ, просто по заданию нужно было отправлять по UDP.

Comment: Да, можно и в первом пакете. Кстати, в него и во все остальные надо бы добавить еще и уникальный id файла, поскольку нужно предусмотреть одновременную передачу нескольких файлов, если обратное не исключается какими-то организационными мерами.

Comment: @avp , согласен с Вами. Плюс, тут получается, что всё равно от управляющих запросов никуда не деться, ведь часть датаграмм, например, может и не дойти. В этом случае нужен некий служебный запрос через тот же tcp на повторную отсылку части данных. А вот с видеопотоком, наверное, можно было бы и наплевать на возможный процент потерь, выставив недостающим пикселям усреднённые значения, вычисленные из непотерявшихся. Так наверное и делают.